# Imbalanced dataset Object Detection

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection-api

Is there a good way to fine tune a model for object detection (in particular, I am trying to use the Tensorflow Object Detection API) for a dataset with highly skewed data? I am trying to use take some categories of COCO and combine it with my own custom data, but there are only about 50 images of my data.

I have tried with just combining the coco data and my own data but it just predicts the coco categories everytime.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using Focal Loss.

See: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.02002.pdf

In the Tensorflow Object Detection model file this would appear as follows:

```
loss {
    localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
    }
    classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid_focal {
            gamma: 2.0
            alpha: 0.25
        }
    }
    classification_weight: 1.0
    localization_weight: 1.0
}
```